Rolling-window beta estimation using monthly returns in R-code
I am trying to estimate market betas for each mutual fund (grsp_id) for each month by using 36-months of past data. I used this tutorial https://www.tidy-finance.org/r/beta-estimation.html#rolling-window-estimation
By code looks the same as in the tutorial:
estimate_capm <- function(data, min_obs = 1) {
  if(nrow(data) < min_obs) {
    beta <- as.numeric(NA)
  } else {
    fit <- lm(excess_return ~ excess_market, data = data)
    beta <- as.numeric(coefficients(fit)[2])
  }
  return(beta)
}

roll_capm_estimation <- function(data, months, min_obs) {
  data <- data %>% arrange(month)
  
  betas <- slide_period_vec(
    .x = data,
    .i = data$month,
    .period = "month",
    .f = ~ estimate_capm(., min_obs),
    .before = months - 1,
    .complete = FALSE
  )
  return(tibble(
    month = unique(data$month),
    beta = betas
  ))
}

final_data <- final_data %>%
  group_by(grsp_id) %>%
  mutate(roll_capm_estimation(pick(everything()), months = 36, min_obs = 24)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ungroup()`

The code runs fine for some funds (by grsp_id) but for some it gives the same error: must be size of X (in this example 233) or 1, not X-1 (in this example 232):
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: roll_capm_estimation(pick(everything()), months = 36, min_obs = 24).
ℹ In group 234: grsp_id = 2005702.
Caused by error:
! roll_capm_estimation(pick(everything()), months = 36, min_obs = 24) must be size 233 or 1, not 232.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
Does anyone have idea what that error means or what it could be related to?
Thanks in advance!
